# .net application w/ DataGridView horizontal scrollbar not showing on specific PC

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I'm using a vb.net based application (VisualStudio 2019) with DataGridViews. On the development pc (Windows 10) the scrollbars shows up, when "enough" data needs to be shown. But when running the same application (the .exe is shared using Syncplicity Sync&Share) the same DataGridView doesn't show the scollbars. User is able to scroll down using the Arrow-Down/Up keys, but not using the horizontal scroll bar (it's just not shown). Interesting, a basic list view show the horizontal scroll bars. BTW, both PC are running the same os version (Windows 10). And it worked in the past :-(

Any idea, where to start searching for the error? Application is about 300.000 lines of code, so not easy to share :-(

Comment: One thing to check is whether the one of the PCs has the app window maximized and one does not. It won't solve the problem, but may allow you to duplicate it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea; just checked with window maximized - no change inbehaviour; development PC shows the Scollbar, production PC doesn't show it regardless of window is maximyzed or not :-(

Comment: just verified that another vb.net application also using a datagridview shows the scrollbars corrupted on one Windows-10 PC while same application (.exe) working proberly on another one. Changed .Net Framework from 4.8 down to 4.7.2 but no change in behavior. Any ideas where to investigate further are welcome.